# How Do I Push Rails 3.0 to Apache/MySQL Production Server

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, apache, production-environment

I'm a Rails student, and I'm guessing my question is a basic one, but it can't be helped. I'm currently going thru a Rails crash course which focuses on using Heroku to test the "production" app. So I'm pretty good at integrating with Heroku, but I have no idea where to turn when it's time to push the app onto my dedicated Apache/mySQL server. I'm assuming there's a gem configuration to handle this? I don't need explicit instructions - if someone can point me in the right direction (which software to use), that would be perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are looking for passenger.

http://www.modrails.com/

Comment: I'm looking into this right now. Ruby / Rails sure does have a heavy learning curve! I'm having fun learning all this new stuff, and it seems that every day I go another gem or 2 deeper into the rabbit hole.

Answer (score 2):

Use capistrano for deployment + passenger (aka modrails) as an interface between the app and apache.

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify:

```
git push heroku master
```

is a command to the program git that tells it to copy the contents of the project to whatever address is associated with the "master" repository. You have git installed on your computer and Heroku has git running on their server with a bunch of snazzy scripting to run whatever ends up inside the servers git repository.
Just so you know, you will not be able to simply "push" to your own server.

On your own server you will typically have a web server (Apache or Nginx or something) that will respond to requests for static files and then an app server (maongrel or passenger or unicorn...) to which your web server will pass requests to. You will need to do some configuration to get the web server passing requests on properly. By far the easiest way to get your Rails app running is installing Apache and using Passenger as your app server.